# How to start 64-bit Java application from 32-bit C++ application?

Tags: java, c++, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I'm using a simple C++ program to run an executable .jar file in Windows 7 64 bit. I expected this to execute 64 bit java, but it doesn't, it executes the 32 bit version.

I'm using the following code:

```
const char* javaw_path     = "javaw.exe";
const std::string memory   = "-Xmx" + user_configured_memory();
const char* jar            = "-jar";
const char* jar_file       = "\"HelloWorld.jar\"";
const std::string cli_args =  get_cli_args(argc, argv);

const char* args[] = {javaw_path, memory.c_str(),
       jar, jar_file, cli_args.c_str(), static_cast<char*>(NULL)};    

const int ret = execvp(javaw_path, args);
```

When the java application starts up it logs the machine architecture as 'x86' rather than  'amd64' as expected. I get this information by checking:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

When I run the same command from the command prompt things work as I expected - The java app logs 'amd64'.

How can I change my start up program to launch 64 bit java?

Comment: Could it be that you just have different PATHs? Your own PATH contains java 64bit dir, while the 32bit app inherits PATH that has java 32bit dir, so it finds 32bit javaw.exe first, and executes it?

Comment: Can you try being explicit about which javaw.exe you want to run e.g. `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\\javaw.exe`

Answer (score 0):

We can have combinations of OS, JDK and Eclipse bit--ness, for instance a 64-bit JDK with a 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit OS, or 32-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse, 64-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse, or 64-bit OS, 64-bit JDK, 64-bit Eclipse. As someone mentioned above, if your programming in C++ on 32-bit, cannot be compiled, it has to be done on 64-bit and of course another 64-bit app to run the exe.

Answer (score -1):

If your C++ program is 32-bit, you can't do it. You must compile the C++ app as 64-bit and then you can call another 64-bit app from the executable.